# Get two random records (different in one attribute) from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Very simple table as an example but no idea how to achieve this:

Example: Table1

```
 ColumnA   ColumnB
   1          A
   1          B
   2          C
```

For two random records: I know I could do like

```
Select top 2 * 
From Table1 
order by NewID()
```

But now I would like to select two random records out but cannot be such a combination that has both '1' for column A, which means the result cannot accept '1 A' together with '1 B', the rest are fine.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: This may depend on how much you want to stress the server, but you really need two separate queries to get the two records. Your first can be retrieved as normal, but your second needs to add a WHERE clause to exclude those rows with matching attribute(s) to the first row chosen.

Comment: @Laughing Vergil, what if I would like to get random 1000 records from table and do not want to use staging table to store the temp result got from logic loop?

Comment: That would depend on the structure and size of the data. You could probably use a recursive CTE to do this somehow, but I have no idea what the load would be like (without testing). My first instinct is actually to extract the row identifiers and differentiation attributes into a temp table,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    DROP TABLE #T
    CREATE TABLE #T(ID INT
                    ,Vals CHAR(2)
                    )
    INSERT INTO #T VALUES
    (1,'A')
    ,(1,'B')
    ,(2,'A')
    ,(2,'C')
    ,(3,'D')
    ,(4,'E')
    ,(5,'E')


    SELECT TOP 2
        ID,
        Vals
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        ID
        ,VALS
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NEWID()) Rnk
    FROM
        #T) T
    WHERE
        Rnk = 1
order by NewID()
```

Comment: I got the main idea though I do not want to create temp table every time. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it, but it can get expensive if your table is very large:

```
;With Random As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By ColumnA Order By NewId()) As RN
    From    Table1
)
Select  Top 2 ColumnA, ColumnB 
From    Random
Where   RN = 1
Order By NewId()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, too!